# custom taxonomy archive gives 404 error page

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to get the archive page of some custom taxonomy.
lets call this custom taxonomy "test".
I've create a "taxonomy-test.php" file, but if I've try to go to "www.domain/taxonomy-test" - I'm getting 404 error page.

If I'm going to "www.domain/taxonomy-test/sub-test" - I'm getting the data from the "taxonomy-test.php" file for the specific "sub-test" in the URL.

But what I'm trying to do is to show on the test archive page ("www.domain/taxonomy-test") some links to the popular sub-tests...

from what I've read, WP don't "understand" to which tax we trying to go, so we get 404 error page.

I didn't find any solutions to that problem rater then do some redirection.
did I miss something? what is the right way to solve it, and get the archive page of "test" taxonomy?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you flush the permalink from Settings -> Permalink. I try with the below code and it's working normally.

```
// Register Taxonomy Test
function create_test_tax() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Test', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Test', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Test', 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Test', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Test', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Test:', 'textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Test', 'textdomain' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Test', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Test', 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Test Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Test', 'textdomain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description' => __( '', 'textdomain' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_tagcloud' => true,
        'show_in_quick_edit' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'test', array('post'), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'create_test_tax' );
```

I also created `taxonomy-test.php` root on the theme and it's working properly.

Comment: thanks for your response . but I'm still getting 404 error page if I'm trying to reach "www.domain/test"